# Netbeans 7.1,ruby-1.9.3-p194, Rails 3.2.3 ,Mac Lion Debugger

Tags: netbeans, ruby-on-rails-3.1, osx-lion, ruby-1.9.3, netbeans-7.1

I can run ruby-debug outside   Netbeans 7.1,ruby-1.9.3-p194, Rails 3.2.3 ,successfully.

But with netbeans ,I keep getting this message.

SEVERE [org.rubyforge.debugcommons.Util]: Error Output: 
/Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': dlopen(/Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle - /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:5:in`'
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/bin/rdebug-ide:9:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/bin/rdebug-ide:9:in`'
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    from /Users/USERHOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in`'
INFO [org.netbeans.api.extexecution.ExecutionService]